# How should I log performance parameters to Sql Server Database (possibly using NLog)

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, logging, nlog

I am quite new to logging. So actually I have couple of related questions.

Now I have quite complex situation in which I am invoking listener callback on the reception of the request on a particular port. As a part of request handling, many methods are called which transact with various servers. 
What I have done currently is:

- I have a `class SqlLog` which contains various static datetime properties corresponding to before and after datetime of server api calls.
- Inside every method in the request handling chain, before and after every server API call, I am capturing date time something as follows:

  SqlLog.BeforeServer1ApiCall = DateTime.Now; 
  ApiCall();
  SqlLog.AfterServer1ApiCall = DateTime.Now;
- At the end I will call `SqlLog.logToSql()` which will finally store those params to Sql Server DB

Now the problem is that if I have `static` properties in `SqlLog`, that all request handling threads will be modifying simultaneously - then it will make a mess. In fact `static`-thingy doesn't work here at all, I guess. I have to create instance of `SqlLog` at the start of every request handling thread, then pass that instance to all method calls that are callec while handling that particular request. Those methods will set corresponding logging field of the instance. At the final step of the request handling I will call `objSqlLog.logToSql()` so it will log information about the single request handling thread as a single record in database table.

**Q.** The problem here is that for this I have to modify the signatures of all methods to accept instance of `SqlLog`. Can anyone guess any other approach that will not require this. Or in fact is there any **standard** / more desirable approach (I guess this must be quite common scenario).

**Q.** I have used NLog for logging to text file and also to WinForms RichTextBox. But I am not able to figure out how to log to Sql Server DB using NLog. The precise thing I am not understanding is how to pass programmatic variables say `int server1ApiTime` variable to NLog or is there any way to specify such binding in `<parameter \>`. I am referring these pages: [1](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target), [2](http://softwarelounge.co.uk/archives/1611)

**Edit 1**: Just now I have learnt that I should be using `Stopwatch.Elapsed` instead of using `DateTime.Now()`. Anyways the problem of logging parameters gathered across different methods in a thread and doing the same for multiple threads simultaneously remains.

**Edit 2**:
Now I realize that I can do this by having a LogManager with a list of Log class instances hashed with threadId. That way I dont have to pass any sort of id across methods explicitly and thus no need to modify method signature. I will do:

```
inside method1()
   logmanager.logs[threadId].api1calltime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
inside method2()
   logmanager.logs[threadId].api2calltime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
inside method3()
   logmanager.logs[threadId].api3calltime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
   logmanager.logs[threadId].logToDb(); //stores all api call times to db in same record
```

So now all params in methods in same thread will form single record in database.

**Q.** Am I going wrong with this approach or there is other more standard way followed?

**Q.** How can I do the same with NLog?

Comment: It's definitely worth using an established logging framework, rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: yess sure but then I am not able to figure it out how should I proceed, noob here :\

Answer (score 1):

Using NLog, you need to separate what you log, from what you save.

You can send anything to be logged - [this page](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Event-context%20layout%20renderer) should explain how to pass custom values. What you then need to do is define your target. this would be your DB, but could equally be a text file, or any of the other targets NLog supports.

For each parameter define a layout, using the layout syntax. you could therefore pass a custom value in as outlined about & map this to a particular parameter.

```
class SomeServerApi
{
    private Logger _log;
    private LogEventInfo _theevent;

    public SomeServerApi()
    {
        _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        _theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, "", "Pass my custom value");
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
       //something happens here

        _theEvent.Properties["MyValue"] = "My custom string";
        _log.Log(theEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: ohkay so the `LogEventInfo` is somewhat like `SqlLog` class that I described. And I still need to pass its instance across method calls?

Comment: Each instance should have it's own log instance & probably a `logEventInfo` instance. you then just call do the `.log` line whenever you need to record the data.

Comment: But what if request handling happens across methods of multiple instances of different classes?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. You can use the any of the layout renders(https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Layout-renderers) if you need to track which thread did what. Each instance does it's own logging. NLog takes care of everything else.

Comment: You mean I should use `${threadid}` somehow to form one record for each request handling thread in the database? But I cant guess how. Is there any tut online explaining the same instead of API reference? Or can u give some more code example? I want record of the form say `{threadId, server1ApiCallTime, server2ApiCallTime, ...}` where `serverXApiCallTime` can be populated in methods of different class instances.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're asking. If you're saying you want 1 log entry to state the times it took for each server request, but that could happen across multiple instances & multiple methods, then you'd need to rethink where you did the logging from, probably the thing that triggered it all, or the thing that knows when it's finished.